# Pandas - duplicate rows and rename a column based on a record frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to duplicate rows based on a `Freq` column which describes how often a row occurs. I want a full table where I create a new `ID` column based on the same logic.

input `df` =

```
ID,            attribute_x, attribute_y, Freq
10001021011     54          54            4
```

Desired output `df`:

```
ID, attribute_x, attribute_y 
10001021011_1   54  54
10001021011_2   54  54 
10001021011_3   54  54
10001021011_4   54  54
```

I have found a way to do this which is quite slow when I run on 100,000 records:

```
def rename(ID, freq):
    
    return str(ID) + "_" + str(freq)

scaled_df = pd.DataFrame()

IDs = df.ID.unique()

for ID in IDs:
    
    tmp_df = df[df.ID==ID]
    
    freq = tmp_df.Freq

    for i in (1,range(freq)):
        
        # copy the df, to keep the original clean         
        tmp_df_cp = tmp_df.copy()
        
        # give a new ID, in the form ID + freq (i)     
        tmp_df_cp['ID'] = tmp_df_cp.apply(lambda x : rename(x.ID,i),axis=1)

        scaled_df = scaled_df.append(tmp_df_cp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by column `Freq` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and drop, then use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups:

```
#default index or not duplicated values are necessary
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.pop('Freq'))]
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].astype(str) + '_' + df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
              ID  attribute_x  attribute_y
0  10001021011_1           54           54
1  10001021011_2           54           54
2  10001021011_3           54           54
3  10001021011_4           54           54
```

Comment: Lightening fast too!